# Gauge and Chart on same report renders incorrecly in report viewer

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I am working on a project in visual studio 2010, and i am using report viewer to display reports (.rdlc files). I am using some components like charts and gauges in my report. When I put a chart and gauge in my report on the same page, it does not render properly. It just renders as a combined image of both in HTML. I searched on [technet.microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bb677570%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and found that there are some rendering rules in the SSRS reports which states that images in report will render together.
When chart and gauge are on different pages in the report, then render correctly. But, when they are on the same page, report viewer just combines them to render in HTML, and they are not rendered properly in a web page. 
I have also tried to put the  gauge and chart in different panels, but still it renders as a combined image. 
Is there any other way to make them render correctly on the same page ?

Comment: Have you tried placing them in separate rectangles or cells in a tablix to keep them apart? Also, you could try the PageBreak - BreakLocation property.

Comment: Yes, I have solved this using Page breaks. However, placing in separate rectangles did not solve the problem.I also found some different behavior when running the report on localhost, and running it on live server. Sometimes, it rendered correctly on localhost, but when I copy the same thing on my staging server, it does not. I am wondering why this different behavior when in both cases it runs on IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a ControlReportViewer try setting SizeToReportContent="True" on its properties

Comment: Stackoverflow is focused on programming with Q&A in English. Please refer to this answer on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow. A Spanish version has been proposed here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/